# Download system file with PermitRootLogin no

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, scp, sftp

I have a remote server with root and regular user access to it, however the direct root access is forbidden using `PermitRootLogin no` in the ssh configuration file. So I'm left with no option to download remote files, it doesn't work via SFTP and SCP neither. Is there still a way?

Comment: P.S. it's a system file, so I don't really wanna `chown` to the regular user

Answer (score 0):

Use Tar

Create the tarball of the file  on your system as root, then scp it to the other system as the normal user, then su to root and untar

that should preserve permissions and ownerships of the file

so:

```
as root on the system copying from

tar cvf file.tar /my/file/here
scp file.tar user@remotehost /tmp
ssh user@remotehost
su - root
cd /tmp
tar xvf file.tar
cp -p file where/file/should/be
```

bit of a round about way but should do it